# Creating a scrollable list of items that can be ordered according to different criteria?

Tags: android, list, sorting, scroll, tags

II would like to create a scrollable list of items that can be sorted according to different criteria that can be chosen by the user from the action bar; I was thinking of a button that says:"Sort by...". I am working on an Android app.

I am developing a tourist guide, or rather, making an app out of a paper tourist guide I have previously written, thus I have a list of monuments through which the user can browse.

It would be great if the user could sort the items of the list in alphabetical order, or according to the rating of the monuments or on the basis of a tag indicating their type (historical building, museum, etc.).

Would it be even possible to display under the name of each item, like a sort of subtitle, a series of dots or stars indicating the above-mentioned rating?

At last but not the least, would it be possible, only when the monuments are sorted by name or rating, to automatically group them by another tag?
Like in some song player apps, when you choose an artist, you get all of his/her songs displayed often grouped by album. In my case the grouping tag would represent the zone in the city of the monuments.

Despite my experience in publishing, I am a newbie in Android (followed just a few courses) and the API docs made me very agoraphobic about coding. I know I am asking much so I don't demand a detailed explanation but a few suggestions about what could be a solution, a bunch of helpful guidelines and some names of specific API docs about Array Lists and sorting methods I should look at.

Thanks already for your help.

Comment: Yes you can sort lists, take a look at Collections (in particular Collections.sort) and how to work with comparables. Yes, in ListView you can use whatever layout you would like (minus some outlying circumstances) for each of your list "items". Take a look at ArrayAdapter (in particular, the getView() method). And lastly, yes, you can sort by anything you would like to, how you implement that sort is up to you (again look at Collections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to have a custom Java Object for a particular item

for example:

```
public class CustomItem{

private String Name;
private int Rating;
private String Tag;

// getters and setters


}
```

Then you can create a Listview with Input consisting of a List of type CustomItem. Here is a good ListView tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

You can then have somethibng like a [Spinner](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/), in which you can add the sort criteria. When the user selects one sort criteria, you can sort the Input List for the ListView and refresh the listview by doing: listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Hope this helps.